# No option on App Store to update High Sierra to Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, mac-appstore

Well, I have MacBook Air (early 2014) with High Sierra 10.13.6 OS and there is no option in AppStore to update to Mojave. I tried downloading directly from [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12) and it stoped after every 500-800 MB, although it resumed from where it was stopped. but, after 100% download nothing happened, it didn't ask me to restart neither any error. So, is there any problem or is it not compatible with my machine.?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, your MacBook should be compatible with the Mojave update.

1. Once the App Store app finishes downloading and installing you should see a installer in the Launchpad (it should automatically open, otherwise try double clicking on it to manually start the installer).
   [image: installer]
2. If this doesn't work out you might want to look at making a bootable USB installer, and proceed with the installation after booting from the USB stick. [See here (Apple Support Documentation)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

Comment: In my case, after 100% download, the icon just vanished (can't find it on launchpad even no .app/.dmg file), and pressing the download button again (from AppStore), started downloading from zero.

Comment: I need help please.